# Save new file name using wildcards with awk

Tags: bash, awk, wildcard

I have 22 files named with numbers that go to 1 to 22. Like:

> bla.chr1.bla.norm
>
> bla.chr2.bla.norm
>
> etc...

I made a simple awk script to add on the first column that particular number of the filename:

```
for i in {1..22}

do 

awk '{print "'"$i "'" $0}' *.chr${i}.*.norm > *.chr${i}.*.norm.chr 

done
```

But now I want to save all the files using the wildcard I used before. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the files ? Then use `cat`

Comment: But can `cat` also expand the wildcards when your saving your file?

Comment: The wildcards work everywhere in bash, they will work with any command.

Comment: It is not working. After using the `awk` command I used: `for i in {1..22};
do; cat *.chr${i}.*.norm.chr >> *.ALLCHR.*.norm.chr;done` but end up with a file named as: `*.ALLCHR.*.norm.chr`

Comment: Wildcards match *existing* files; they don't "remember" what the previous wildcard on the line matched and use the same values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, gawk

```
awk '{match(FILENAME,"chr([0-9]+).",t); print t[1] $0 > FILENAME".chr"}' *.norm
```